# White spaces capturing with sed

Tags: regex, sed, substitution

I need some help with sed regex substitution.

From the following line:

```
Provides          mysql
```

I want to get:

```
Provides          mysql-5.5
```

The best solution I was able to come with is:

```
sed -i "s/\(Provides\)\(\s\)*\(mysql\)/\1\2mysql-5.5/g" my_file_containing_the_line
```

but the result is not as I want:

```
Provides mysql-5.5
```

Which is not perfect because I lost the white spaces between "Provides" and "mysql-5.5"

Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
"s/\(Provides\)\(\s\)*\(mysql\)/\1\2mysql-5.5/g"
```

`\2` group does not contain all spaces

`"s/\(Provides\)\(\s*\)\(mysql\)/\1\2mysql-5.5/g"` will work.

```
$> echo "Provides          mysql" | sed "s/\(Provides\)\(\s*\)\(mysql\)/\1\2mysql-5.5/g"
Provides          mysql-5.5
```

Beside that you can use `--regexp-extended` option to suppress redundant escaping:

```
$> echo "Provides          mysql" | sed --regexp-extended "s/(Provides)(\s*)(mysql)/\1\2mysql-5.5/g"
Provides          mysql-5.5
```

Or even

```
$> echo "Provides          mysql" | sed --regexp-extended "s/(Provides\s*)(mysql)/\1\2-5.5/g"
Provides          mysql-5.5
```

Comment: It works. Thanks for the --regexp-extended option to suppress the boring escaping.

Answer (score 4):

Change this:

```
\(\s\)*
```

to this:

```
\(\s*\)
```

so that the capture-group contains all of `\s*`, instead of just a single `\s`. (With `\(\s\)*`, the capture-group ends up containing only the last whitespace character.)

Actually, for that matter, you can combine all the capture groups, and write either:

```
sed -i 's/\(Provides\s*\)mysql/\1mysql-5.5/g' my_file_containing_the_line
```

or:

```
sed -i 's/\(Provides\s*mysql\)/\1-5.5/g' my_file_containing_the_line
```

Comment: Thanks. I like your variation. Sorry, I can't accept more than one response. I'm voting up.

Comment: Dude, it's not *all* about the rep.

Comment: @ДМИТРИЙ МАЛИКОВ I accepted your answer, don't you get reputation from that?

Comment: @redsonic: Yes, accepting an answer gives +15 reputation; upvoting an answer gives +10. Dmitriy Malikov is just being greedy. :-P

Comment: > Dude, it's not all about the rep. <-- Wait, but about what?

Answer (score 0):

This might work for you:

```
echo "Provides          mysql                " | sed '/^Provides/s/mysql/&-5.5/'
Provides          mysql-5.5
```